# Embed a website in a div with Jquery

Tags: jquery, embed

I'm trying to embed a website a website into a div, but the problem i'm having is that the website i'm embedding isn't filling up the whole div.

The code i have right now:

```
$("#Rectangle").html('<object data="http://dmatthams.co.uk/thing/gwd/">');
```

(Relevant jsfiddle)
http://jsfiddle.net/j997K/

As you can see, the website that is embedded isn't filling up the whole div. Any ideas on how i could fix that?

(And also, i need to use Jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to set the `<object>` to

```
object {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Also you had two `ID` with the same name, that does not work! ;)

## JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/j997K/1/

Comment: Wow, didn't know it was so simple :P Thanks!

Edit: But do you know how i would remove the scrollbars?

Comment: @ElvarP Sorry, I had a JSFIDDLE, deleted it, did not come to an end to get rid of the scrollbars, that was the short version. The long version: If you ever manage to get into the `DOM` of the inner website, please give me a notification! ;)